# If a cleric takes the Ritual Caster feat and picks the wizard list, are they able to scribe rituals that are on both classes' spell lists?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, cleric, rituals

I am playing a cleric. I would like to take the Ritual Caster feat at level 4 to access some wizard spells for utility.

Can my cleric spend the material cost to add rituals shared by both classes (like Detect Magic, Detect Poison, Identify, Gentle Repose, etc.) to the ritual book? Or do I need to find a wizard based written source?

Comment: Related (not duplicates): [Who can create copies of spells that can subsequently be copied into spellbooks, etc?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79148/who-can-create-copies-of-spells-that-can-subsequently-be-copied-into-spellbooks), [From what items can a wizard learn his spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103260/from-what-items-can-a-wizard-learn-his-spells), [What exactly are the sources from which you can copy spells into a Book of Shadows?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79611/what-exactly-are-the-sources-from-which-you-can-copy-spells-into-a-book-of-shado)

Comment: Are you asking if you can add cleric rituals to the wizard ritual book the feat gives you?

Comment: @Jason_c_o Correct. I was hoping I could free up prepared slots by adding my shared rituals to my book. As I see it now, when I take the feat my PC can understand written cleric and wizard spells and I need a duel use (scroll) or wizard (spellbook) to scribe the ritual spells in a wizard incantation to my book. Further rationalizing it my cleric rituals are not written down preparing them after a long rest is a connection to my deity, not a physical source.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## You need to find a written source

As per the [Ritual Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/ritual-caster) feat's description (PHB, p. 169; emphasis mine):

> **If you come across a spell in written form**, such as a magical spell scroll or a wizard’s spellbook, you might be able to add it to your ritual book. The spell must be on the spell list for the class you chose, the spell’s level can be no higher than half your level (rounded up), and it must have the ritual tag. The process of copying the spell into your ritual book takes 2 hours per level of the spell, and costs 50 gp per level. The cost represents
> material components you expend as you experiment with the spell to master it, as well as the fine inks you need to record it.

The way I understand that is you can add rituals to your rituals book, you simply need to copy it from a written source and pay the costs and spent the necessary time.

So, to be very precise, as long as the spell you want to copy is from the spell list you have chosen when taking this feat **and** has the ritual tag **and** is not higher level than half your own level (rounded up) **and** you have a written source for it, then you can include it in your rituals book.

Eg.: You have taken Ritual Caster (Wizard) as a cleric. You find a scroll of detect magic. As a cleric you have access to that spell, can cast it as a ritual but to do so you need to prepare it after a long rest, taking one of your preparation slot for the day. Since it is also a spell in the wizard's spell list, you could add it to your ritual book and from then on you wouldn't need to prepare Detect Magic to be able to cast it as a ritual (and as a ritual only), as long as you have your rituals book in hand.

Comment: There's always the possibility of scribing the scroll so that you have a written source.

Comment: Yes but to be able to scribe the scroll, one needs to know the spell. So you still need access to someone who knows the spell who then has to give you a written source for it. A wizard would be able to forego having to actually scribe a spell by lending his spellbook, but a sorcerer, bard, cleric or druid would need to pay the costs of scribing the scroll.

Comment: Yup. It also takes more time. But if you have the time, money, and DM permission, it greatly expands your options, especially for cleric, druid, or paladin.

Comment: @Catar4 the PC already knows the spell, in this case, so that's no a concern

Comment: If the PC already knows the spell, it means he chose the same spell list for his Ritual Caster feat than the spell list his class gave him ? What's the point of doing that ? Remember the feat description, you have to chose a spell list and then you can copy ritual spells from that list and that list only into your ritual book. What would be the point of chosing the same spell list you already have access to, besides being able to have access to those ritual spells without preparing them ? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: I don't feel this answers the actual question.

Comment: There's the question of "Can my cleric add spells shared by both classes" kinda answers itself through the description of the feat which is very clear on that point, which is why I decided to answer only the second part "do I need to find a written source". Since the actual phrasing of the question was "A or B ?" I think I answered it correctly. I'll still add a precision to my answer after your comment, Jason.

Comment: @Catar4 Freeing prepared cleric spell slots was the hope.

Comment: @Catar4 Makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.